# Tensorflow U-Net using way too much memory

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, out-of-memory, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I'm training a U-Net CNN on a custom dataset, but whenever I train the model, I get an error saying that the memory resources have been exhausted. This does not make sense, though, as my batch size is only 8 (512 x 512 png images).

I am working on VS code with a CUDA-enabled GPU.

I have already tried some popular fixes such as:

```
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

but nothing has worked

Comment: Why do you think it does not make sense? What's your GPU? 512x512 images are already exhaustive, they are even more if there are 3 channels.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running out of memory with U-net, you can try [MobileNet (v2/v3)](https://keras.io/api/applications/mobilenet/). There are pretrained versions of it available in keras. It is specifically developed to reduce the number of parameters and run on end user hardware (see [depthwise separable convolutions](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-depthwise-separable-convolutions-and-the-efficiency-of-mobilenets-6de3d6b62503?gi=76f1c453af5f)).

Unless you're running with a high end cloud GPU it's not unlikely that you run out of RAM on the GPU as you advance to models using tens or hundreds of millions of parameters. For example, an NVidia 4070 has 12GB of RAM, which means it can fit ~3B f32s. Keep in mind that you have to produce intermediate results for backprop in addition to the weights. There's a reason the A100s have 80G HBM.

If you are using a `tf.keras.Model` you can print a nice overview by calling `model.summary()` that will tell you how many params you're using in each layer and in total.